# How to integrate newest Twilio SDK with React Native

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I have an application made with React Native and I need to integrate Twilio SDK into my project, so I can use it to make calls etc. with Twilio from the application. I found a few guides that seems to be outdated, because Twilio just switched to new Programmable Voice SDK.

Any suggestion or advice is very appreciated.

Comment: You can use **opentok** for voice as well video calling  here is link https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to implement the Programmable Voice SDK, so you can use VoIP (Voice-over-IP) functionality?
Twilio itself doesn't offer any react-native libraries. Therefore, if you're looking to implement Twilio functionality on the device, you'd need to either make a wrapper for the Twilio libraries yourself or use a third-party library, like [react-native-twilio-programmable-voice](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice).

You can find an usage guide in the `README` on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 4):

I have made this package that you can check as well: https://github.com/MrHertal/react-native-twilio-phone

It uses last Twilio Programmable SDK.

Comment: This has several issues in dependent library and with RN 0.70.x

Comment: here is the link of issues I encountered...

https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApZh6coQtw6dgqo7ef5Mb2YZ3ZMrGQ?e=2y6yDW